# How to make Clickable Image area with zoom in & out in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an image as a background and I want to make **certain parts of this image clickable with zooming in and out** , Is there any way to do something like that ??

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new view for your gesture recognizer. The recognizer implements a locationInView: method. Set it up for the view that contains the sensitive region. On the handleGesture, hit-test the region you care about like this:

0) Do all this on the view that contains the region you care about. Don't add a special view just for the gesture recognizer.

1) Setup mySensitiveRect

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect mySensitiveRect;
  @synthesize mySensitiveRect=_mySensitiveRect;
  self.mySensitiveRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 240.0, 320.0, 240.0);
```

2) Create your gestureRecognizer:

gr = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    // if not using ARC, you should [gr release];
    // mySensitiveRect coords are in the coordinate system of self.view

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(mySensitiveRect, p)) {
       //Add your zooming code here
    } else {
        NSLog(@"got a tap, but not where i need it");
    }
}}
```

The sensitive rect should be initialized in myView's coordinate system, the same view to which you attach the recognizer.

Comment: Can you give me Tutorial step by step ??

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a demo app called PhotoScroller that implements a zoomable, scrollable set of images (in a page view controller, but you don't need that.) That would be a good starting point for what you need.

Their sample apps used to be built into the Xcode docs. Since Xcode 6 I haven't seen them linked in the docs any more.

You can download PhotoScroller from [**Apple's online iOS Developer Library**.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) (link)

Comment: I downloaded this library and i like it but i want to split my image into clickable areas but with the condition that whenever I zoom in and out, the clickable area coordination still the same, so please help me with this :) .

Comment: You have a unique requirement. You need to develop  unique code to handle that requirement. The PhotoScroller app uses a normal UIScrollView, which handles the tap, pinch, and pan gestures in that view. You'll somehow need to override that behavior. I can think of a few ways to do that, but it would be involved, and pretty advanced stuff. More than I'm willing to do online for free.